# ng-Click not working in angularjs after clicking for the first time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a code that should display a pop-up to the center of the div when you click on it. On clicking on it the first time it pops up the Hello div but on clicking on it the second time nothing happens. Please assist me! This is my complete code.
This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div style="height:200px; background-color: red; position:relative">
    <div id="cover" ng-click="show = true" ng-click="show = false">
      Cover
    </div>
    <div ng-show="show" ng-click="show = true" ng-click="show = false" class="slide">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the script.js

```
console.clear();

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
});
```

This is the style.css

```
div#cover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.slide {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: 1s ease bottom !important;
  display: block !important;
}
.slide.ng-hide {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note - You put `ng-click` attribute twice in your `div.slide`

Comment: yeah. that is for true and false clicking

Comment: this is wrong. U probably meant ng-click="show = !show"

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: <div id="cover" ng-click="show = true" ng-click="show =!show">
      Cover
    </div>
    <div ng-show="show" ng-click="show = true" ng-click="show =!show" class="slide">
      Hello
    </div>

Comment: I dont understand the attack

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/WN8v2riSYhhMyOgbZiWO?p=preview

Comment: Solved by my answer http://plnkr.co/edit/nuvfDlj8XfMEzfFnEjGO?p=preview

Comment: I dont get why this question should get a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all `ng-click` in your all div tags. Just copy past my below `ng-click`instead of your `ng-click`.

try with using ternary operators.

`ng-click="show = show == false ? true : false"`

Working demo : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nuvfDlj8XfMEzfFnEjGO?p=preview)

Comment: good luck.... this is just my thinking..... grow up our creativity and bit level coding solutions :+1 .. thanks

Comment: Yeah. It evolves with time. Anyway, what about if I want to make the Hello pop-up appear at the center of the div. How possible is it.

Comment: You need setup the css changes, Please ask this for a new question :)

Comment: I will do that immediately I make an attempt. Dont want a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I will try something like this:

```js
 $scope.changeShow = function (){
    $scope.var = ($scope.var === false) ? true : false;
  }
```

```html
<div ng-show="var" ng-init="var=true" class="slide">
      Hello
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="changeShow()">
```